# Subplots too much compacted

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to plot three graph using matplotlib, but the way the images are displayed is not clear, I try using methods such as **plt.tight_layout()** and **plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.5, top=1.0, wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)**, but non of them works.

I am not pretty sure if the problem is the IDE that I am using (Visual Studio Code), or is there is any way to graph singles plot but inside the same python function. If any one has any idea of how to improve the way the graph is shown.

```
def program_graph(year):
    ...
    fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols = 1)
    risk_info_srv_evesa.plot.bar(ax = axes[0])
    risk_info_act_pln.plot.bar(ax = axes[1])
    final_db.plot.bar(ax = axes[2])
    axes[0].title.set_text('SRV-EVESOS per Program')
    axes[1].title.set_text('Action Plan per Program')
    axes[2].title.set_text('SRV-EVESOS Vs Action Plan')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.4, bottom=0.1, right=0.5, top=1.0, wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)
    plt.show()
```

The best solution I thing that would be to show each graph individually, but I do not want to implement different functions for each one of the graphs. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Remove the line `plt.subplots_adjust(...)`. Then show your output and explain clearly what's wrong with it.

Comment: I tried and now the questions is edited with the image. I would like each image to be more visible. None of the names of the X axis is properly readable.By the way this image is with the plt.subplots removed.

Comment: This is with `plt.tight_layout()`? This shouldn't happen. If you can provide a [mcve] and state which version is in use I can investigate.

Comment: I just noticed that if I remove the "bar" and just let the ".plot" it works perfect, but do not use a bar chart, do you know why?

Comment: You can use the `figsize` parameter when creating your figure to make your plotting area wider

Comment: Still not working, I tried with multiples values of figsize and the view continue with the same problem

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I actually try with a minimal reproducible example and it works, I thint that maybe it was related to a problem with the columns name. At the ned I change it, instead of using a vertical a use an horizontal accommodation and at the end it works, tks